# Can't click button

Tags: vb.net, button

So, I'm developing a YouTube-Simulation-Game. Currently I'm working on the YouTube Website. In the game you should be able to customize your channel avatar and banner. So, like on the real YouTube site, I created two buttons which, when clicked, open an `OpenFileDialog`, in which the player should select the image file. The only problem is, that you can't click the button for some reason. **Here's what the form looks like:**

[image: The Form in the Designer]

And here's my code:

```
#Region "Edit Buttons"
    Sub ShowEditBanner() Handles BannerBox.MouseEnter
        BannerEditButton.Visible = True
        AvatarEditButton.Visible = True
        BannerEditButton.BringToFront()
        AvatarEditButton.BringToFront()
    End Sub

    Sub ShowEditAvatar() Handles AvatarBox.MouseEnter
        BannerEditButton.Visible = True
        AvatarEditButton.Visible = True
        BannerEditButton.BringToFront()
        AvatarEditButton.BringToFront()
    End Sub

    Sub HideEditBanner() Handles BannerBox.MouseLeave
        BannerEditButton.Visible = False
        AvatarEditButton.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Sub HideEditAvatar() Handles AvatarBox.MouseLeave
        BannerEditButton.Visible = False
        AvatarEditButton.Visible = False
    End Sub
#End Region

    Sub EditAvatar() Handles AvatarEditButton.Click
        If AvatarFileDialog.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            Try
                Dim Img As Image = Image.FromFile(AvatarFileDialog.FileName)
                AvatarBox.Image = Img
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Invalid file.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

Any help would be apprechiated!

~ Mika / OneByte_

Comment: You should not create event handlers manually, use the drop downs in the code editor window or change the Property Pane view to Events and click the one you want.  `EditAvatar` is not a legal event signature

Comment: This is a bug that happens when you try to show/hide the button when the mouse enters/leaves it. I bumped into this myself a while ago, let me check my code and write an answer for you...

Comment: To add to Plutonix's comment, the arguments to the event handlers you've shown should be `(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)`. If you use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) then problems like that will be pointed out for you.

Comment: I agree that he should not be adding handlers manually, but really it doesn't matter when added this way. If it's declared correctly it's the same thing and the drop down would find it. If you add it via the AddHandler code then I would say that's wrong unless you really know what you're doing. In some cases you need to add handlers that way. Adding controls dynamically is one example.

Comment: Are you still having issues with this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are experiencing is a bug that happens when the button's `MouseEnter` event tries to show the button at the same time as when the AvatarBox's `MouseLeave` event tries to hide it.

To fix it, you simply need to check in the `MouseLeave` event if the mouse is still within the bounds of the control. If not: hide the button.

```
If AvatarBox.ClientRectangle.Contains(Me.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)) = False Then
    AvatarEditButton.Visible = False
End If
```

The logic applies to both your controls.

Comment: That kinda worked. I can now click the AvatarEditButton, but not the BannerEditButton. My code looks like this now: http://pastebin.com/4RidjS8A

Comment: @OneByte_ : Well the same method of course applies to `BannerBox.MouseLeave` too if you just change to the correct button and container names. I just didn't bother writing both of them :). **EDIT:** As I see in your code you can just remove the entire `HideEditBanner()` method and declare your other method like this instead: `Sub HideEditAvatar() Handles AvatarBox.MouseLeave, BannerBox.MouseLeave`.